# What is the proper way to import and use css styles in reactjs with victoryjs?

Tags: reactjs, victory-charts

How can we do for example: import './styles.scss' and use it on for example a VictoryLabel like:

```
<VictoryLabel className='some class from styles.css' />
```

I have tried but I can not get it to work.

Comment: The `VictoryLabel` component from the Victory charting library does not natively support applying styles via CSS classes out-of-the-box, the Victory library usually handles styling via props rather than CSS classes.

You can either create a custom wrapper component or use inline styles to achieve your desired look.

Comment: Thanks @jimmykurian! by props do you mean something like (for VictoryLabel): **backgroundStyle={victoryLabelBackgroundStyle}**? Where **victoryLabelBackgroundStyle** could be in a separate .ts file?

Comment: here is an example from the Victory Charts documentation:
https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/victory-label/#inline